# Kohana: проблема с модулем database

Tags: kohana, auth, база-данных

Подключил бд. Сделал авторизацию с помощью модуля `auth`, пытаюсь войти, пишет ошибку

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

Не правильный логин, пароль, хост к базе данных.
В application/config/ есть database.php? там верные ник-пароль указаны?

Ссылка на документацию http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/config